# Postgres: Function check duplicates in table

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I have table with multiple duplicates and I want to make from these a function. Could you please help me to make a function from this code? thanks.

```
SELECT id_member,id_service,amount,date, count(*) as number_of_duplicates
from evidence
GROUP BY id_member,id_service,amount,date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_for_duplicates()
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
SELECT id_member,id_service,amount,date, count(*) as number_of_duplicates
from evidence
GROUP BY id_member,id_service,amount,date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE ‘plpgsql‘;
```

Comment: So you want your function to simply return that result?

Comment: Yes. I have trouble with creating function from these peace of code.

Comment: I think its because you return VOID and have no out parameter - try returning a table instead?.. although I don't understand why you want to wrap it up to plpgsql - no arguments, no variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function should return a result set it needs to be declared as `returns table ()` or `returns setof`

You also don't need a PL/pgSQL function for that, a simple SQL function will do and is more efficient:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_for_duplicates()
RETURNS table (id_member integer, id_service integer, amount numeric, date date, number_of_duplicates bigint) 
$BODY$
  SELECT id_member,id_service,amount,date, count(*) as number_of_duplicates
  from evidence
  GROUP BY id_member,id_service,amount,date
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

You didn't show us the definition of the table `evidence` so I had to guess the data type of the columns. You will need to adjust the types in the `returns table (...)` part to match the types from the table.

Having said that: I would create a view for things like that, not a function.

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: `date` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's also a keyword but more importantly it doesn't document what the column contains: a release date? An expiration date? A due date?</sup>